# android webview wrapper of a website lost session and ask for login after app goes to background

Tags: android, webview, cookiemanager

my android pp is a wrapper of a website and i have a webview that loads the website ,
the problem is when app goes to background and after user click on app icon again , it send user to login page and it lost user authentication . i am using
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true)

but is not working for me.

Comment: did you test this approach ?  :mywebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

Comment: yes I did, doesn't help :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.